# RelayCommand not executing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, relaycommand

I'm trying to execute a RelayCommand (which is in my CodeBehind) using the RelayCommand from Galasoft MVVMLight.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    MyCommand = new RelayCommand(Methode);
}

#region Commands
public RelayCommand MyCommand { get; private set; }
#endregion

private void Methode()
{
    int i = 1;        
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

Unfortunately, the command is not firing/the method is not being called. Other binded elements like ImageSource, ... are working fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try creating the new `RelayCommand` before setting the `DataContext`.

Setting the `DataContext` triggers the data binding engine to update the bindings. Since the `MyCommand` property is not set yet, the `Button`s `Command` will be null. Creating a new `RelayCommand` after setting the `DataContext` will not notify the `Button` of the update to the property.

Creating the `Command` before setting the `DataContext` is one solution, another one is implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raising the `PropertyChanged` event after setting `MyCommand` (or in the setter, requiring a backing field).

Comment: working, thanks... Didn't know it's that simple. Also thought it would make no difference if I set the DataContext at the beginning or at the end.

Comment: It makes a difference in this case, since setting the datacontext triggers the updates for the bindings. The Command binding finds your command property, but it isn't set yet. After setting the datacontext, setting the command property doesn't notify your button it has changed, so the button won't know that.

Comment: No problem, should have done that in my answer in the first place, I'll update it.